# How can I authorize to send a GET request from one GCLOUD function to another

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

Trying to hit a gcloud function's endpoint via GET to trigger the http function.  All I need to do is hit the endpoint with some param values to trigger the function.

We are not allowing unauthenticated on these functions so I need to authenticate in order to send it but cannot for the life of my find a working example on how to do this.

I have read [this](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating) and quite literally gone in circles following the links in their documentation trying to find what I need to do to set this up.

The function I am hitting sends a message when everything has updated for the day

```
https.get(`${endPoint}`, (resp) => {
  // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
  resp.on('end', () => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data).explanation); //  Should return the text set int he function, current, "It's Done"
    res.status(200).send(`SQL INSERTs have all been run for client(${clientId}) and they have been notified`);
  });
}).on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error: " + err.message);
  res.status(200).send(`There was an error running SQL INSERTs  for client(${clientId}) and they have not been notified, error ${err.message}`);
});
```

In the logs for the function I am trying to hit it returns

```
The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated invocations or set the proper Authorization header. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#unauthorized-client
```

So I am specifically trying to figure out what I need to do, exactly, in order to authenticate and hit the endpoint via a GET request.

Since posting this question I have also created a service account and downloaded the credentials, which is set to `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, so if there is a solution using that JSON file I can try that as well.

Comment: See [Authenticating function-to-function calls](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#authenticating_function_to_function_calls)

Comment: seen that like 20 times today, that documentation is horrid, all it did for me was produce errors.  I did however get a working example, which looks nothing like any of the documentation, but as long as it works I'm happy.